# Delete items from hashtable (java)

Tags: java, data-structures, hashtable

I have a class Section with several methods including methods get_key() and get_angle(). Items of type Section are added to a hashtable implemented in class Hashtable.
According to my task I should delete such elements from the hashtable which have bigger value of function get_angle() than given_value.

```
class Hashtable{
private Section[] hash_array;  //array of cells of the hashtable
public int size;

public void remove_given(double given_value)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (hash_array[i] != null)
        {
            double value = hash_array[i].get_angle();  //value of needed function to compare
            if (value > given_value)
            {
                int key_ = hash_array[i].get_key();  //get key for the item in order to delete it       
                Delete(key_);   //delete item       
            }
        }           
    }
}

}
```

But the method doesn`t delete any elements. I checked the method Delete() separately and it works just fine as well as other methods called on this method . I really need to figure it out. So I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: Would probably have to see your Section class first.

Comment: I don't see where you are initializing size?  It should be based on the size of the Hash.

Comment: I initialize in the constructor of the class Hashtable. I can add this part of the code if you need to.

Comment: A few notes here:  1) You should not use double if your concerned about precision (which most of the time, you probably are)... use BigDecimal instead.  Also, use normal Java conventions for naming variables and methods (e.g. instead of hash_array, use hashArray, removeGiven instead of remove_given etc).

Answer (score 0):

Debug your code, does it enter the for-loop. How do you initialize the value of `size` variable? If you forget to initialize it by default it will be zero. It is better to get the size from the `hash_array.length`.

Comment: It does enter the loop. I guess the problem is inside of it.

Comment: I initialize size through constructor of the class Hashtable

Answer (score 0):

For one thing you're using the uninitialized global var, `size`, the size used in the `for` loop needs to be the size of the Hash collection.  Also how is the Hash initialized?  Does it contain what you think?  I'd follow the aforementioned suggestion to step through the code with a debugger, perhaps the keys aren't what you think they are...

Comment: Even if I write hash_array.length instead of variable size it doesn`t solve my problem. Anyway thanks for you help.

Comment: Answer changed, see above.

Comment: Ok, I`ll try. Thanks for help.